# Remove all data in a collection relating to user

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to remove data in a collection, however, I'm getting `remove failed: Access denied`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**DB - Files.find**

```
"_id": "",
"url": "",
"userId": "",
"added": ""
```

Path: `file.js`

```
   Template.file.events = {
      "click .delete-photo" : function () {
        Files.remove(this._id);
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are uninstall autopublish package use method as above answer:

```
Meteor.methods({
 removePhoto: function (photoId) {
 check(photoId, Meteor.Collection.ObjectID);
 Files.remove(photoId);
});
```

And on your client:

```
Meteor.call("removePhoto", this._id, function(error, affectedDocs) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } else {
   // Do whatever
   console.log("success");
  }
});
```

and if you uninstall insecure package please publishand subscribe the collection.

```
Meteor.publish('collectionname',function(){
 return collectionname.find();
}
```

and subscribe:
 `Meteor.subscribe('collectionname);`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making this into a Meteor method.

Server side code:

```
Meteor.methods({
  removePhoto: function (photoId) {
  check(photoId, Meteor.Collection.ObjectID);
  Files.remove(photoId);
});
```

You should consider to remove the insecure and autopublish packages by typing these commands in your console:

```
meteor remove autopublish
meteor remove insecure
```

Below there is an example of how to publish the Files collection (here you also could add security features, such as only find and publish files belonging to user with correct id):

```
Meteor.publish('files',function(){
   return Files.find();
}
```

And on your client:

```
Meteor.call("removePhoto", this._id, function(error, affectedDocs) {
   if (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
   } else {
    // Do whatever
    console.log("success");
   }
});
```

Here is the code for subscribing to the Files collection:

```
Meteor.subscribe('collectionname');
```

Read about methods, publish and subscribe over at Meteor docs. Links: http://guide.meteor.com/methods.html,  https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/security-with-methods, https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe